# Robolectric with AndroidAnnotations make tests hang/not running

Tags: java, android, robolectric, android-annotations

I am trying to configure a basic application with the Robolectric library. I am using the lattest version (3.0) as well as the lattest AndroidAnnotations version (3.3.2) and Gradle 1.4.0.

After struggling with few issues such as AndroidHttpClient exception, I managed to have it done with a very trivial test.

Now I wanted to further test with an Activity and I can't make the tests run. The tests hang somehow and never yield (yellow spin for each tests).

It seems to happen because of the @Before setup as it yields when commented. But why can't I setup my activity using this annotation? Especially while it yields when I use the annotated Activity (instead of the generated Activity_) which is not the proper way to test when using AndroidAnnotations.

Here is my truncated test class that still can't get executed...:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MapActivityTest {

  private MapActivity_ mMapActivity;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mMapActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MapActivity_.class).create().get();
  }

  @Test
  public void checkActivityNotNull() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(mMapActivity);
  }

}
```

I am also using the Java 1.8 if that could be of any help.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this issue?

Thanks already!

**UPDATE:**

Tried after downgrading to Java 7 and same result.

Comment: Do you have good internet connection? Robolectric downloads big dependencies first. Also try to run from command line. I would also try to downgrade to Java 7, i am not sure Robolectric can support Java 8.

Comment: Yeah solid internet connection and downloading took a while :) Tried in command line as well and same result, it does not yield. I will try Java 7 I was guessing this could be a problem.

Comment: Dang... not easy to downgrade while having Java 8. Can't get rid of it!

Comment: Ok, finally set up Java 7 for Android Studio. But unfortunately same result...

Comment: Is this a big project? Can you share it? If not, try to debug and pause it when hanging, and check out the current stack trace

Comment: Not a big project ;) It is located here: https://github.com/StephenVinouze/BasicLocationApp

Comment: Also tried to debug and it stuck somewhere in reflection. I would advice to ask question on Robolectric github project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AndroidAnnotations is no issue for robolectric.

After some thread dumps I found the looping code. The class `KBLocationProvider` contains following snippet

```
boolean isPermissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
if (!isPermissionGranted) {          
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
}
```

And the `checkSelfPermission(...)` method never returns true. This method calls a `checkPermission(..)` methods on a context. A short [search](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=checkPermission) for `checkPermission(..)` showed a ShadowApplicationTest which shows the usage for checkPermission.

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/867a805f36d7492ba80f150836bf88b97c3248e0/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplicationTest.java#L532

After adding following line your test is finishing.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Shadows.shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application).grantPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    mMapActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MapActivity_.class).create().get();
}
```

Looks like you have an issue with an endless loop when the permission is denied.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nenick you did quite some digging. I will have to be more careful about the new permission system in the future ;)